# Как добраться до нужного метода? C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Я начинаю осваивать ООП и у меня есть задание на калькулятор, получаем на вход список чисел и операций, затем выполняем. Операции нужно добавить перегрузкой через `override` и я вот вроде бы написал идею самих классов, а теперь не могу даже вызвать метод, подскажите как это сделать, вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Calculator
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public List<int> Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        public List<string> Opereations = new List<string> { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

        public abstract class Calculations
        {
            public abstract int Calculate(List<int> numbers, List<string> operations);
        }
        public class Plus : Calculations
        {
            public override int Calculate(List<int> numbers, List<string> operations)
            {
                return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
            }
        }

        public class Minus : Calculations
        {
            public override int Calculate(List<int> numbers, List<string> operations)
            {
                return numbers[0] - numbers[1];
            }
        }

        public class Multiply : Calculations
        {
            public override int Calculate(List<int> numbers, List<string> operations)
            {
                return numbers[0] * numbers[1];
            }
        }

        public class Devide : Calculations
        {
            public override int Calculate(List<int> numbers, List<string> operations)
            {
                return numbers[0] / numbers[1];
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Исправил код в вопросе, вы имели в виду это?

Comment: Я откатил правку назад, чтобы ответ соотвествовал коду из вопроса.

Comment: @aepot Да, хорошо, я не знал, что правка так влияет

Comment: Представьте, пришли вы почитать Stackoverflow, смотрите в вопрос, потом в ответ, и не видите между ними связи. Это неудобно, верно?

Comment: @aepot Да, конечно, я понимаю вашу правку, я просто сказал, что не знал, что так изменится вопрос от правки

Comment: Как вариант, если ответ уже дан, вы можете добавить новую версию кода в конец вопроса, а не заменять старую, чтобы донести обновленную информацию до отвечающего. Если ответа еще нет, то можете править изначальный вопрос, просто в этот раз ответ и исправление вопроса произошли примерно одновременно, ничего страшного.

Comment: @aepot Понял, хорошо

Comment: @aepot А можете подсказать? Если я в метод `Calculate` , который находится в классе `Calculator` хочу принимать лишь 2 списка, первый это числа, второй это операции, то мне нужно использовать видимо работу с польской записью, потому что может быть несколько операций и чисел > 3, и к тому же изменить работу метода, чтобы он мог работать со списком?

Comment: Обратная польская запись, да.

Comment: @aepot А то что вы использовали `switch` уместно ли, просто полиморфизм должен был вроде как и убрать необходимость использовать его

Comment: Нет, полиморфизм никак не относится к ветвлению. Просто ветвление при полиморфизме можно делать на этапе создания экземпляра, а не по факту обработки данных. Сначала выбирается тип и создается, а где-то потом используется. Отношение символ-операция, оно в любом случае где-то должно быть. Это может быть switch, словарь, или поиск по коллекции в готовых экземплярах, неважно что, но если связи нет - значит ее  нет, никакой магии.

Comment: Понял, спасибо еще раз, буду думать над  обратной польской записью!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не должны использовать вложенные классы, это вас и путает. Разместите все классы рядом друг с другом, а не внутри. Станет легче.

Простой пример.

```cs
public abstract class Calculation
{
    public abstract int Calculate(int left, int right);
}

public class Plus : Calculation
{
    public override int Calculate(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}

// ... остальные типы

public class Calculator
{
    public int Calculate(int left, int right, char opChar)
    {
        Calculation op;
        switch (opChar)
        {
            case '+': op = new Plus(); break;
            default: throw new NotSupportedException("Неверная операция");
        }
        return op.Calculate(left, right);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator();
        int result = calc.Calculate(2, 2, '+');
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это будет работать же если мне нужно с листом работать?

Comment: Я просто исправил как вы сказали и что-то получается, попытаюсь разобраться сам еще посидеть, а потом уже если не получится буду разбирать ваш пример.
Меня и правда очень путала вложенность, а по заданию ее и не должно быть

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin ну вы перепишите класс `Calculator` как вам нужно, пусть у него будет метод, который принимает списки. Ваш вопрос был про полиморфизм, что там в аргументах методов должно быть - вам решать. То есть от того что у вас немного другие требования к входным данным, суть построения классов не меняется.

Comment: Да, отлично, просто уточняю, на мой вопрос вы ответили, спасибо большое!